# Autoregressive forecasting with distinct models problem

Tags: time-series, linear-regression

I got $n$ features - $f$ (used as an input as well as a target). Since I'm using linear regression and want to avoid situation in which weights of a model fit not only for $fi$ but for all of $f$ (while I predict $y_{f_i}$) - I've implemented distinct models for each feature (that's what my teacher suggested me). Each model is trained on $X_f$ with all $f$ and $y_{f_i}$ which is only related to $f_i$. Everything works fine but I want to use an autoregressive approach to forecast a few steps in the future. It's problematic because at each autoregressive step, $\hat{Y_{f,t+1}}$ should be concatenated with $X_t$ and when using distinct models each predicts only targets for $f_i$ and it seems like it is impossible to obtain $\hat{Y_f}$ to perform the autoregressive step. How should I approach this problem? Am I missing something or my reasoning is incorrect?